# Sh Script runs fine manually, fails in crontab

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I get this error while running thru crontab

> /aws-cron-job/Ap_Hourly_xxxDelete.sh: 1: ./aws-cron-job/Ap_Hourly_xxxDelete.sh: ec2-describe-snapshots: not found
>
> ./aws-cron-job/Ap_Hourly_xxxDelete.sh: 1: ./aws-cron-job/Ap_Hourly_xxxDelete.sh: ec2-delete-snapshot: not found

This is my script: filename = **xxx.sh**

```
ec2-delete-snapshot --region ap-southeast-1 $(ec2-describe-snapshots --region ap-southeast-1 | sort -r -k 5 | grep "Ap_Hourly" | sed 1,4d | awk '{print $2};' | tr '\n' ' ')
```

This is my **cronjob**:

```
30 05-15 * * 1-6 ./aws-cron-job/Ap_Hourly_xxxDelete.sh > ./aws-cron-job/Ap_Hourly_xxxDelete.txt 2>&1
```

I can run this script manually but not through Cronjob. Where is the problem in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `ec2-delete-snapshot` and `ec2-describe-snapshots` in the `$PATH`? Maybe you should modify `PATH`? Or use the full path to those programs?

Comment: Your uses of `./` aren't going to work in cron. You need to change those to reference the full path.

Comment: Yes, ec2-delete-snapshot and ec2-describe-snapshots are in $PATH

Answer (score 1):

The environment that commands run with as cron jobs is very limited, things like `$PATH` and `$HOME` are not what you'd expect.

To analyze this, use `crontab -e` to add the job `* * * * * /bin/bash -c env >/tmp/cron.env`, then look inside that file to see what `bash` knows about when started as a `cron` job on your machine. The job will run every minute, so when you're done debugging, remove it, also with `crontab -e`.

The error `ec2-describe-snapshots: not found` suggests that `ec2-describe-snapshots` might not be found in `$PATH` when the script runs as a cron job. To fix this, first find its normal location from the a shell with `which ec2-describe-snapshots`. Then, either use full path in script (`/some/path/ec2-describe-snapshots ...`), or adjust `$PATH` in script (`PATH=/some/path:$PATH`) before calling `ec2-describe-snapshots`.

Also, it's a good habit to use full paths in `crontab` entries, both for executables and for log files. However, the error in OP would not come from this.

Comment: SHELL=/bin/sh        
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin          
PWD=/home/ubuntu        
LANG=en_US.UTF-8        
SHLVL=1      
HOME=/home/ubuntu     
LOGNAME=ubuntu       
_=/usr/bin/env        

This is what i get from above cronjob

Comment: Perhaps `ec2-describe-snapshots` is not in that `PATH`? See edit.

Comment: Yes it is in $PATH. I can simple run from any where

Comment: bin/sh: 1: /home/ubuntu/aws-con-job/Ap_Hourly_SnapshotDelete.sh: not found

This is coming now.

Comment: What are the full paths to `Ap_Hourly_SnapshotDelete.sh` and `ec2-describe-snapshots`?

Comment: /home/ubuntu/aws-cron-job/Ap_Hourly_SnapshotDelete.sh - this is the full path of file location.

Comment: What else is in the script? In OP you posted a single line. Is there a shebang like `#!/bin/sh`? Is there anything else?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you should place only absolute paths in your cronjobs. As seen in your question, you wrote:

```
./aws-cron-job/Ap_Hourly_xxxDelete.sh
```

and I think you should write:

```
/<rootpath>/aws-cron-job/Ap_Hourly_xxxDelete.sh
```

Comment: /home/ubuntu/aws-cron-job/Ap_Hourly_SnapshotDelete.sh - this is the full path of file location